# Dual printer managment from single application

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

How to manage more than one printer from single C# windows application? Requirement is there should be only one print button and it will give print command to printer as per configuration in application.

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough to do.  Project + Properties, Settings tab, add a setting named "Printer".  Then use it like this:

```
    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName =
            Properties.Settings.Default.Printer;
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
```

Somebody with admin privileges will have to edit your app.exe.config file to set the printer name.  Given how likely it is for the printer name to change, I would *strongly* recommend you make this a User scoped setting and add an Options + Select Printer menu command to allow the user to select the printer.  Use PrintDialog.